# Looping LSTM model predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I'm curious on how I approach implementing predictions in a for loop using a pre-trained model and tokenized weights.

I currently give the model one string of text each loop through and it predicts the sentiment. I can't give it a dataframe as I want the script to run at real time, transcribing spoken speech to text and then returning the sentiment. Then proceeding on to the next person and so on.

i.e. iterating through a list of people and calling loaded_model.predict(padded_text) each iteration results in following warning:

My code works but I receive `WARNING:tensorflow:7 out of the last 12 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x000001E5E152D670> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.`

I've done a bit of research but still confused. Could someone please break it down for me/offer potential solutions.

Code:

```
 while len(storage) < len(jurors):
    print('Juror' + ' ' + jurors[len(storage)] + ' ' + 'is speaking:')
    init_rec = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio_string = []
        audio_data = init_rec.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio_data = init_rec.listen(source) #each juror speaks for 10 seconds
        audio_text = init_rec.recognize_google(audio_data)
        print('End of juror' + ' ' + jurors[len(storage)] + ' ' + 'speech')
      
        #storage of all spoken text (maybe convert to dict for key, value with juror name)
        storage.append(audio_text)
        audio_string.append(audio_text)
       
        #funtions
        cleaned = clean_text(audio_string)
        tokenized = tokenize_text(audio_string)
        padded_text = padding(audio_string, tokenized) #fix padded text elongating rows
        
        
        loaded_score = loaded_model.predict(padded_text)
        y_loaded_pred = np.argmax(loaded_score, axis = 1).reshape(-1,1)
        y_sentiment = np.vectorize(label_dict.get)(y_loaded_pred)
```

Comment: I know that it has something to do with tf graphs and having to create a new one each iteration. I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: Put the code that produces the  warning.

Comment: Code is posted.

Comment: Have you a method decorated with  @tf.function inside while loop?